# Storing Vector, Matlab

Tags: matlab

I need to store the vector PVX in my program, I have done the pre-allocation trick but it does not work. I keep getting the last entry. Why is it so hard to store stuff. I want the vector PVX=[numbas,POW] for each numbas so i can refer back to them.

```
n=100;
primlist=2;


for numba=1:n;
   if mod(2+numba,primlist)~=0
   primlist=[primlist;2+numba];
   end
end



PVX=zeros(size(1,26)); %Pre-allocating vector

for numbas=2:n


prims=zeros(size(primlist));
  pow=prims;
  for k=1:10
    for i=1:length(primlist)
        if mod(numbas,primlist(i).^k)==0
            prims(i)=primlist(i); % sum of all the powers of prims, such that prims divide  numbas
            pow(i)=k;

            POW=pow';

            PVX=[numbas,POW]; 

        end

    end

  end


end

PVX
```

Answer (score 0):

You are overwriting PVX each time that you loop through i and k. If you want to store PVX within the i-loop, you can use

```
PVX(i,:) = [numbas, POW];
```

The pre-allocation does not really work since you do not know the size of PVX in advance (at least in the way that you set up the code).

Comment: yes the size of PVX is 26, numbas plus all the POWS(25) will be 26